# Socket IO emitWithAck Event Handler getting NO ACK, Swift

Tags: swift, socket.io

After `socket` connection is made, i am calling an event `emitWithAck` with `timingOut(after: 10)` after 10 seconds `Event Handler` returns **NO ACK** as result.

If I give `timingOut(after: 0)` , the `Event Handler` is **not called**

Below is my code,

```
socket.emitWithAck("getUserPoints", jsonUser.object as! SocketData).timingOut(after: 10) {data in
}
```

**Note** : This issue is occurring not all the time. In some scenario, i am facing this issue. Can anyone help in this?

Comment: See if it is your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286357/swift-socket-io-the-event-sent-right-after-connection-is-not-executed

Comment: Thanks @chengsam. But i am emitting only after connection is established.

`lazy var onConnect: NormalCallback = {[unowned self] (data, ack) -> Void in
        socket.emitWithAck("getUserPoints", jsonUser.object as! SocketData).timingOut(after: 10) {data in
            
        }
    }`

Comment: Did you figure  it out @AustinMichael, because Im running into the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the Same issue and I fount the I am calling `socket.emitWithAck` before the socket is connected 
check the `socket.status` 
I have resolve it by adding a handler like this

```
      socket.once(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
      socket.emitWithAck("getUserPoints", jsonUser.object as! SocketData).timingOut(after: 10) {data in
       }
        }
```